# Programmatically move registry keys

Tags: c++, registry, enumerate

Does anyone know how I can programmaically move a registry from HKEY_LOCAL_MCAHINE to HKEY_CURRENT_USER?

I wrote a recursive function that uses RegEnumKeyEx and RegEnumValue, but it appears that RegEnumValue returns all of the values under the top level key.

For example, if the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp\KeyName1 and has 3 values under it and I have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApp\KeyName2 and that has 2 values.  It looks like RegEnumKeyEx is returning the proper keys, but when I call RegEnumValue for the first Key (ie. KeyName1) i get all 5 values returned and not just the 3 under that key.

Hope that all makes sense... am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help

Here is a snippet, if it helps:

```
void CArgusApp::RecurseSubKeys(CString csStartKey)
{
    CQERegistry reg;

    HRESULT hr = reg.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\" + csStartKey, KEY_QUERY_VALUE );

    CStringArray csaDataNames;
    reg.GetAllDataNames(csaDataNames);
    for (int j = 0; j < csaDataNames.GetSize(); j++)
    {
        CString csValueName = csaDataNames.ElementAt(j);
        TRACE(csStartKey + " - " + csValueName);
    }

    CStringArray csaKeys;
    reg.GetAllSubKeys(csaKeys);
    for (int i = 0; i < csaKeys.GetSize(); i++)
    {
        CString csKey = csaKeys.ElementAt(i);
        this->RecurseSubKeys(csStartKey + "\\" + csKey);
    }

    reg.Close();
}
```

i.e.  GetAllDataNames above simply calls RegEnumValue and GetAllSubKeys call RegEnumKeyEx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through all the registry functions, I found this: SHCopyKey or I can use this: RegCopyTree for Vista and later.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert at this, but try something like this.

```
  RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
  @"SOFTWARE\\" + csStartKey, 
  false);
Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey
        (myKey.ToString());
```